# laravel - home route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning `Laravel`, and for my first project I'd like to create my portfolio. However, the first task I have to do is confusing me.

So I created my templates, `layout.blade.php` and `home.blade.php`. That makes sense to me, but now how do I tell Laravel, or how do I `route` to `home.blade.php`?

I'm looking for an explanation rather then just code. I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, a `view` in `MVC` application is just a part of the application and it's only for presentation logic, the `UI` and one doesn't call/load a view directly without the help of another part (controller/function) of the application. Basically, you make a request to a route and that route passes the control over to a `controller/function` and from there you show/load the `view`. `So` it's not a tutorial site and it's also not possible to explain about `MVC` here, you should read about it and for `Laravel`, it's best place to understand the basics on it's documentation, well explained with examples, anyways.

In case of `Laravel`, you should create a `controller/class` or an `anonymous function` in your `apps/routes.php` file and show the `view` from one of those. Just follow the given instruction step by step.

### Using a Class:

To create a [route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) to your `Home` Controller you should add this code in your `app/routes.php`

```
// This will call "showWelcome" method in your "HomeController" class
Route::any('/', array( 'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome' ));
```

Then create the `HomeController` controller/class (create a file in your controllers folder and save this file using `HomeController.php` as it's name) then paste the code given  below

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function showWelcome()
{
        // whatever you do, do it here
        // prepare some data to use in the view (optional)
        $data['page_title'] = 'Home Page';
        // finally load the view
        return View::make('home', $data);
    }
}
```

If you have `{{ $title }}` in your `home.blade.php` then it'll print `Home Page`. So, to use a view you need a `controller` or an `anonymous function` and load the view from the controller/function.

### Using an anonymous function:

Also, you can use an anonymous function instead of a `controller/class` to show the `view` from directly your route, i.e.

```
Route::any('/', function(){
    // return View::make('home'); 
    // or this
    $data['page_title'] = 'Home Page'; // (optional)
    return View::make('home', $data);
});
```

Using this approach, whenever you make a request to the home page, `Laravel` will call the anonymous function given in/as route's `callback` and from there you show your view.

### Make sure to extend the the master/main layout in sub view (home):

Also, remember that, you have following at the first line of your `home.blade.php` file

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
```

It looks confusing, you may rename the main layout (`layout.blade.php`) to `master.blade.php` and use following in your `home.blade.php` instead

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

### Read the doc/understand basics:

You should read [Laravel's documentation](http://laravel.com/docs) properly, (check [templates](http://laravel.com/docs/templates) to understand `blade` templating) and also read some [MVC examples](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=mvc%20example%20php&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=mvc%20example%20php&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6340j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), that may help you too understand the basics of an `MVC` framework (you may find more by googling) and some good posts about `MVC` on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20mvc).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. One quick question though, just to make sure I understand. Every route needs a controller, for example, a get() to return the template 'home' will require a controller that has a function to return 'home' as well, correct?

Comment: @devs, welcome and Yes, exactly but you can use an anonymous function in the route declaration instead of a controller, see the section `using an anonymous function` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check it [routing in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/routing).

You need to use route file and controllers

Create needed function in your Controller file and create a template file for example

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        return View::make('user.profile', array('user' => $user));
    }

}
```

you need to create view file views/user/profile.blade.php

```
View::make('user.profile', array('user' => $user)) == views/user/profile.blade.php
```

And you should read it http://laravel.com/docs/responses and also this http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-view

Comment: Yes, I read that carefully :), as I said, I know that I need to use routers, but how? And What should my controller look like?